# Slideshow not coming under the Header

Tags: javascript, html, css

My slideshow is not coming under the header, it is next to the header. I tried **flex** but the slider just broke. I tried increasing the padding and margin but that did not work too.

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tia6E.png)

**HTML CODE**

[HTML Code](https://ghostbin.com/8x16B) **(Full Code)**

```
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slides">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
          <div class="slide first">
            <img src="img/Temp1.jfif" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/temp2.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/" alt="">
          </div>
          
          <div class="navigation-auto">
            <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
            <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
            <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
            <div class="auto-btn4"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation-manual">
          <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
          <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
          <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
          <label for="radio4" class="manual-btn"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**CSS CODE**

[CSS Code](https://ghostbin.com/IYJ1E)  **(Code too big)**

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
  counter++;
  if(counter > 4){
    counter = 1;
  }
}, 5000);
```

Please Help me fix this bug.

Comment: Instead of sharing external links for the code, you should add the code to your question

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: My code it too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `display: flex` from `body` styles in CSS

```css
body{
    margin-bottom: 1000px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    /*display: flex;*/ /*Remove this*/
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
  }
  

  .slider{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-content: bottom;
  }
  
  .slides{
    width: 500%;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .slides input{
    display: none;
  }
  
  .slide{
    width: 20%;
    transition: 2s;
  }
  
  .slide img{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
  }
  
  .navigation-manual{
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .manual-btn{
    border: 2px solid #40D3DC;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  
  .manual-btn:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  
  .manual-btn:hover{
    background: #40D3DC;
  }
  
  #radio1:checked ~ .first{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  #radio2:checked ~ .first{
    margin-left: -20%;
  }
  
  #radio3:checked ~ .first{
    margin-left: -40%;
  }
  
  #radio4:checked ~ .first{
    margin-left: -60%;
  }
  
  /*css for automatic navigation*/
  
  .navigation-auto{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 800px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 460px;
  }
  
  .navigation-auto div{
    border: 2px solid #40D3DC;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  
  .navigation-auto div:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  
  #radio1:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn1{
    background: #40D3DC;
  }
  
  #radio2:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn2{
    background: #40D3DC;
  }
  
  #radio3:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn3{
    background: #40D3DC;
  }
  
  #radio4:checked ~ .navigation-auto .auto-btn4{
    background: #40D3DC;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Name</title>
</head>

<!--Connections-->
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<script src="TS/script.ts"></script>
<script src="JS/slide.js"></script>

<!--Header-->
<body>
  <div id="Header">
  <header class="text-gray-600 body-font">
    <div class="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
      <a class="flex title-font font-medium items-center text-gray-900 mb-4 md:mb-0">
        <img src="img/Fashion Bud Logo.png" width="70" height="70">
        <span class="ml-3 text-xl">Name</span>
      </a>
      <nav class="md:ml-auto flex flex-wrap items-center text-base justify-center">
        <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900" style="cursor: pointer;">Home</a>
        <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900" style="cursor: pointer;">Magazine</a>
        <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900" style="cursor: pointer;">Gallery</a>
        <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900" style="cursor: pointer;">Blog</a>
        <a class="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900" style="cursor: pointer;">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    </div>
  <hr class="hr">

  <!--Slider-->
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="slides">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
          <div class="slide first">
            <img src="img/Temp1.jfif" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/temp2.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/" alt="">
          </div>
          
          <div class="navigation-auto">
            <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
            <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
            <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
            <div class="auto-btn4"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation-manual">
          <label for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
          <label for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
          <label for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
          <label for="radio4" class="manual-btn"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
header, .slider{
  width: 100%;
}
```